# Passing Dynamic Values sent to php array_strip produces errors

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to pass dynamic GET values via an AJAX script to PHP, I noticed that dynamic values sent to "array_strip" produces the error below. Everything works, if I hard-code the values, but I need it to work with dynamic values.  Not sure what I am doing wrong... Thanks in Advance!

***"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/books.php on line 120"***

```
<?php
$p = trim($_GET["p"]);//START
$limit = trim($_GET["limit"]);//NUMBER OF RESULTS

//HARDCODING VALUES WORKS
foreach (array_slice($obj_data->docs, 0, 5) as $book) {    
.....
}

//DYNAMIC VALUES FAILS
foreach (array_slice($obj_data->docs, $p, $limit) as $book) {    
.....
}
?>
```

Not sure what was going on with my code but converted strings to integers, and renamed some of the values, fix below

```
<?php
 $st = trim($_GET["p"]);//START
 $limit = trim($_GET["limit"]);//NUMBER OF RESULTS

 $int_s = (int)$st;
 $int_l = (int)$limit;

 //var_dump($int_s, $int_l); -> int(1) int(5)

 foreach (array_slice($obj_data->docs, $int_s, $int_l) as $book) {  
 ....
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: can you show a `var_dump()` of `$p` and `$limit`

Comment: My guess is `$p` and `$limit` are not what you think they are. Try `var_dump($p, $limit)` to inspect those variables. Let's say they were empty, for example. The result would be `array_slice([1,2,3], "", "")` which would give you `NULL`. And obviously `NULL` is **not** a traversable value that `foreach` can take. They could also be non-numeric strings, which would cause the same result: `array_slice([1,2,3], "a", "b") === NULL`

Comment: Trim is for strings... just saying

Comment: var_dump() produces -> string(1) "0" string(1) "5"

Comment: Force casting to array. `foreach ((array)array_slice($obj_data->docs, $p, $limit) as $book) {   `. Better make sure the parameters are valid. Example `$p = trim($_GET["p"]) ?? 0;`.

Comment: As you might have noticed (comment under the posted answer) I cannot reproduce your issue. feeding `array_slice()` with 'dynamic' variables (`numeric strings`) in this case works just fine. The only issue might then be your `$obj_data->docs`, are you sure it always returns an array? You might want to check.

Answer (score 1):

The non-buggy way to do this is to prevent the values `$p` and `$limit` from being anything other than numbers. Since non-numeric values will cause `array_slice()` to fail and return `NULL` which will cause `foreach` to fail with the above error. Also always check to make sure you have an array before handing it to `foreach`.

So instead try something like this:

```
const MIN_P = 0;
const MIN_LIMIT = 10; // set some default minimum to use

$p = filter_var(
    $_GET['p'] ?? MIN_P,
    FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    ['flags' => FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE]
) ?? MIN_P;

$limit = filter_var(
    $_GET['limit'] ?? MIN_LIMIT,
    FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    ['flags' => FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE]
) ?? MIN_LIMIT;

// ensure that we always have an array if even a zero-length array
$array = is_array($obj_data->docs) ? $obj_data->doc : [];

foreach (array_slice($array, $p, $limit) as $book) {    

    /* ... */

}
```

So the above code does some basic error-checking to prevent bugs like the one above. It's safer to use since it can't produce any errors.

Comment: feeding it with `strings` works just [fine](https://3v4l.org/aunNH)...

Comment: I never said you can't give it a `string`. I said "***non-numeric values*** will cause array_slice() to fail". So `array_slice($arr, "foo", "bar")` returns `NULL`. `"1"` and `"2"` are still a numeric values. However, `""` and `"blah"` are not.

Comment: the `var_dump()` of the OP seems to indicate he's feeding it with strings, which is interesting, as it does not seem to yield expected result.